# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL

Tags: eclipse, html, cordova, failed-to-load-viewstate

We have faced this type of  problem.We are Developing phonegap app.We don't changed any code.But unfortunately my eclipse stop.And then we changed project location.then we open html page in browser.We got error like this [image]

Please guide to us.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your app inside a web server, that solved my problem, or you can simply delete "history.replaceState()" in your jquery.mobile.js file, if you don't use the browser history in your mobile app
Waiting for chrome developers to fix this issue from the last update.